# large file upload from android to soap web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

How to upload large file(50 MB) from an android device to a soap web service. I am using ksoap android library for soap requests. There is on solution that I can think of to convert file into byte array add that byte array to soap request using `addProperty()` this will work fine for small files but for larger files I may get an out of memory exception.
I have been googing for hours trying to find a solution to this. Does soap support multi part upload ? and if yes a link to an example would be highly appreciated and if no then what else can I do ?